# typecast array to unsafeMutablePointer

Tags: arrays, swift, pointers

I have a function that takes `UnsafeMutablePointer<GLfloat>`. But I got  array of *GLfloat*s `[GLfloat]`. How to get the raw memory pointer of it?

Comment: Just pass `&array` to the function. Examples here: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=6.

Comment: Thanks It worked! I was afraid it would become `UnsafeMutablePointer<[GLfloat]>` so I have tried `&array[0]` which gave error.